# Search array of dissimilar hashes

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

I have an array of hashes, each of which has non-normalized values like this:

```
arr = [{
    id: 0,
    type: 'character',
    person: {
      name: 'Steve Rogers',
      weapon: 'Shield',
      known: true
    }
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    type: 'organization',
    company: "Pym Industries",
    tech: 'Shrinking suit'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    type: 'character',
    person: {
      name: 'Tony Stark',
      weapon: 'Ironman Suit',
      known: false
    }
  }]
```

Some of the hashes are different. I want to get a subarray of hashes whose person I know, i.e., `arr.person.known` is `true`. The result should be like:

```
subarr = [{
    id: 0,
    type: 'character',
    person: {
      name: 'Steve Rogers',
      weapon: 'Shield',
      known: true
    }
  }]
```

I tried:

```
b = arr.select{|x| x.person.known}
b = arr.reject{|x| if x.person then x.person.known}
```

But I bump into `` NoMethodError: undefined method `person' for Hash:0x007fc5f6f587f0 ``.

Comment: Note that `arr['person']` and `arr.person` are the same thing in JavaScript, but not in Ruby. A hash is not the same as an object. There are things you can do to make Ruby hash behave that way, but it is not encouraged, as it can cause both subtle and not-so-subtle bugs.

Comment: @Amadan Understand that. I'm actually working with associated records in rails. Where each entry has_one person and a person belongs_to :entry, inverse_of: :entry, optional: true

Comment: You said "array of hashes", tagged it as "hash"... if you actually have an array of objects, `arr.select { |x| x&.person&.known }` is clearest.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this one

```
arr.select { |item| item.fetch(:person, {})[:known] }
```

or

```
arr.select { |item| (item[:person] || {})[:known] }
```

or, from Ruby 2.3.0

```
arr.select { |item| item.dig(:person, :known) }
```

More verbose but maybe clearer

```
arr.select do |item|
  person = item.fetch(:person, {})
  person[:known]
end
```

or

```
arr.select { |item| item[:person] && item[:person][:known] }
```

Comment: Or even `arr.select { |x| x[:person]&.[](:known) }` (but `dig` is really nice).

Comment: Or that. But I think there are enough options :D